# 5.5.52-MariaDB with Magento 2 will it work properly

Tags: mysql, magento, mariadb, magento2

am trying to import Magento 2 database on 5.5.52-MariaDB. while it was import I got an error the import stop at admin_user ERROR: **"MySQL Error There can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT clause"**

I am wondering if 5.5.52-MariaDB isn't the right version and that's why I am getting this error.

As per [Magento 2 Docs](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html) it does not say which version of MariaDB it requires. Does anybody knows or have more imformation about this? Thank's in advance.

Comment: It seems unlikely to need two timestamp columns, both with a default.  What's up?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple `TIMESTAMP` columns with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in the `DEFAULT` clause are allowed in MariaDB starting from **10.0**. Neither MariaDB 5.5 nor MySQL 5.5 support them.

Comment: Hi elenst. Thank's for the input my MariaDB sure  will needs an upgrade.